# How to get JSON file from CSV with restful using flask

Tags: python, json, rest, flask

I want to get my CSV file to JSON file using restful with flask framework so I could get it in my Xcode project. I've manage to import the CSV and get it as JSON data but I can't get the JSON file, and my data presented not as I expected (everything print in lines and not in the JSON struct).
I need the data to be organized and the JSON file.

my code:

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from json import dumps

e = create_engine('sqlite:///salaries.db')

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

class Departments_Meta(Resource):
    def get(self):
    #Connect to databse
    conn = e.connect()
    #Perform query and return JSON data
    query = conn.execute("select distinct DEPARTMENT from salaries")
    return {'departments': [i[0] for i in query.cursor.fetchall()]}

class Departmental_Salary(Resource):
    def get(self, department_name):
        conn = e.connect()
        query = conn.execute("select * from salaries where Department='%s'"%department_name.upper())

        result = {'data': [dict(zip(tuple (query.keys()) ,i)) for i in query.cursor]}
        return result

api.add_resource(Departmental_Salary, '/dept/<string:department_name>')
api.add_resource(Departments_Meta, '/departments')

if __name__ == '__main__':
     app.run()
```

Comment: i don't see any csv?